# Font Awesome icons not showing withou 'www'

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, font-awesome

i'm developing a website with drupal 7.x.
I'm using font awesome icons downloading the font-awesome folder into my project and linking the css in my head (I had the last font-awesome version).
The problem is that in the site with 'www' icons are showed correctly, but if i try without 'www' the icons became squares.
The site in this case is 'planetmotors.it'.
Any suggestion? I don't want to redirect all 'non www' traffic to 'www'.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check if awesome icons has some restriction depending on the domain where it is used. then use wildcard symbol *.planetmotors.it

The most crucial thing you should do is the redirection from non-www to www or reverse. If you do not do this you will have issues with duplicate content and it will results to the lower position in SERP. I do recommend you to redirect non www to www (not only because icon issues). What are your reasons to avoid this redirection?

Comment: Thank you Eduard. I solved redirecting (via htaccess) all "non www" traffic to "www". 
your comment give me the input for study the SEO advantages of this redirection, and i have to give a reason to you. The best pratice is to use only one version. I past i avoid this redirection for give the user the freedom to choose which domain navigate, but in conclusion, is not a problem. Thanks

Comment: if you follow the SEO rules you are doing the best. they are not just like somebody in google said it will be like this. They are trying to improve the usability of the web to the best. :) When you meet someone with a hendicap you will see what is this all about. Somebody should tell this to angular developers :P :D